# Finding a story where aliens warn mankind away with math

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember much of the book, but I do remember that humans were approaching something. I believe it was a cache of weapons or something that aliens were storing/hiding on Earth.

And the aliens left a "warning message" to the humans by somehow giving off signals (don't remember exactly how) that ended up to be invalid and/or impossible math equations (things like 1=0) meant to warn anybody away as math is a universal language.

I know it's not much to go on, but thank you very much for your assistance.

Comment: Hello! Do you remember approximately when you read the story? And was it a short story or full length novel?

Comment: "Aliens and math" rings _Contact_, by Carl Sagan. But this may be a popular trope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [*Deep Storm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Storm)

This thriller by Lincoln Child deals with a cache of alien micro-black holes left on Earth, and the strange illnesses caused by the protections placed around them by said aliens. The plot points mentioned in the question can essentially be read off from the Wikipedia description:

> Despite this, Ping manages to resurrect the data using a crude form
>   of magnetic force microscopy, and as they peer onto the screen they
>   realize that the other messages included [*math omitted here*], **other impossible mathematical equations**. Because
>   humans place passive and active ways to warn people of the danger of
>   such stored weapons, **Crane assumes aliens think the same way and the
>   sentinels are actually a message warning advanced civilizations to
>   stay off earth. This deciphers the mathematical expressions because
>   the “forbidden” mathematical maneuvers are the only way aliens can
>   communicate with other more sophisticated races.**